# Скрипт не выполняется

Tags: php, mysql

На локальной машине тестирую вот этот скрипт

```
$dump_path = "backups"; 
$host = "localhost";  
$user = "root";  
$pass = "";  
$command=$dump_path.'mysqldump -h '.$host.' -u '.$user.' dental > 
dental_b.sql';
if  (system($command)){
echo "YES" ; 
} 
else 
{
echo "Error" ;
}
```

Но почему то скрипт не выполняется и показывает Error хотя все данные от базы верны (Стоит XAMPP)

Скрипт найден здесь на [гитхабе](https://gist.github.com/SahilC/4165155)

Comment: Первый пример https://habrahabr.ru/post/105954/ А тут http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/mysqldump.html полное описание

Comment: Спасибо Visman то что надо !

Answer (score 0):

Cтрока `$command` будет выглядеть как `backupsmysqldump ...`. Вы хотя бы пробел поставьте или другой символ, который нужен (потому что даже с пробелом это выглядит как-то странно).

Comment: Дело в том что это всё поднято на mysqli ( а вот насчет пробела или другого символа можно подробнее ?

Comment: нашел этот скрипт на гитхабе вся беда в этом. Если можете посоветуйте функцию для бекапа БД через mysqli